# CSS3 transition in angle from a new position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to make a transition in angle starting from the element's last position during several transitions?

```
div2 {
  transform: translateX(90px);
  transform: translateY(90px);
  transform: translate(110px,110px);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5AuhV/)

Basically what i would like to do is to make the div move 110px from the top and 110px from the left of the 'Transition 2' state.

I am using jQuery.Transit plugin.

Comment: I noticed in your jsfiddle that you included the `html` `head` and `script` tags. Did you know that jsfiddle can include the tags for you? Also, +1 for clever use of F00.

Comment: @ZackT. clever use of `F00`? Red is a pretty common debugging color because it is quick to type and is very visible.

Comment: @ZackT. jsfiddle example is a quick fork of another SO question, not mine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's built-in incrementation syntax:

```
//Transition 1
$('#div2').transition({ x: "+=" + 90 });
//Transition 2
$('#div2').transition({ y: "+=" + 90 });
//Transition 3
$('#div2').transition({ x: "+=" + 110, y: "+=" + 110 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var x = 0; // horizontal base value
var y = 0; // vertical base value

//Transition 1
$('#div2').transition({ x: x = x + 90 });
//Transition 2
$('#div2').transition({ y: y = y + 90 });
//Transition 3
$('#div2').transition({ x: x = x + 110, y: y = y + 110 });
```

This way you are increasing the base value at each stage

**Edit**

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5AuhV/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the CSS3 transition-delay property. I'm not sure if this works with multiple transitions, but you should try it.

<s>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp</s>

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-delay-property